# Error: Could not find or load main class clean in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

While running testng.xml file in eclipse I faced this error.But run via command line I can able to run.can anyone guide me how to fix this one

Comment: Without seeing your code I guess noone can help you

Comment: While running testng I passed vm argument as "clean test -Duser=''flipcart'".This only gives me a issue.So now I got it. I should pass argument as "-Duser="flipcart"".